# Infinite wait time when using await

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I am trying to do a refresh token but the async function runs infinitely without returning any results.

I'm doing it based on the tutorial:  [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXJ6QK03JmA&t=281s).

File users.js

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = {
    loginUserTkRefresh: async (req, res) => {
        const refreshToken = req.body.token
        
        if(!refreshToken) return res.status(401);
        
        try {
            await jwt.verify(refreshToken, process.env.REFRESH_ACCESS_TOKEN);
        } catch (err) {
            return res.sendStatus(403);
        }

        const accessToken = jwt.sign(
            { id: 1 },
            process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN,
            { expiresIn: 200 }
        );
        res.send({ accessToken });
    },
};
```

File api.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const router = express.Router();
const user = require("../actions/api/users");

router.get("/users", authenticate, (req, res) => {
    const users = [{ id: 1, email: "adam@op.pl", password: "12321" }];
    res.send(users);
});

router.post("/auth/login", user.loginUser);
router.post("/auth/refresh", user.loginUserTkRefresh);

function authenticate(req, res, next) {
    const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(" ")[1];

    if (token === null) return res.status(401);

    jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN, (err, user) => {
        if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
        req.user = user;
        next();
    });
}

module.exports = router;
```

File index.js

```js
const express = require("express");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();

const { port } = require("./config/config");
const apiRouter = require("./routes/api");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// routes
app.use("/api", apiRouter);

// serever
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening...");
    console.log(`\tAddress: http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Request:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/refresh
Content-Type: "application/json"

{
    "token":" "
}
```

Maybe I made a syntax mistake somewhere but I've checked many times with no results. I also tried moving everything to one file but that didn't help too.

Comment: How do you know that the `async` function runs infinitely?  What exactly are you observing?  What request?  What does it do or not do that you think it's supposed to?  Why is the `authenticate()` function in your question as it isn't referenced anywhere?

Comment: @jfriend00
I am using the REST client plugin, which shows me that it is waiting for a response, in the bottom left corner, and does not receive any error or result.

Comment: Did you track through both `authenticate()` and `loginUserTkRefresh()` where the code flow goes?  You can do that simply by just sprinkling unique `console.log()` statements through your code or (even better) by setting breakpoints in the debugger.   This is elemental debugging which should always be done before asking for help.  That should identify what code path it is taking and will probably explain what's going on.

Comment: Do you have code somewhere that registers the `api` router with Express?

Comment: Your `api.js` code in your question appears to have duplicate code segments.  Since this wouldn't run, I assume it's a copy/paste error in your question.  Please fix.

Comment: Not an error, but `await jwt.verify(...)` is pointless.  The jsonwebtoken module does not support promises so therefore `await` will not do anything useful here.  `jwt.verify()` without a callback is synchronous.

Comment: Also, this `if (token === null) return res.status(401);` is wrong.  If the `authorization` header does not exist in here `const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];`, then `authHeader` will be `undefined`.  That will not satisfy `if (token === null)`.  You should probably change it to just `if (!token)`.  There appear to be several errors in that video.

Comment: I have fixed the incorrectly pasted code in the post.
Actually you are right to what ```if (!token) return res.status(401);``` but unfortunately it did not solve my main problem. I debugged the code and it seems to me that it is not the async that is the problem but ```jwt.verify(...)```.

Comment: Ok I changed ```status()``` to ```sendStatus()``` and got a 401 error, so for some reason I can't get the value ```const refreshToken = req.body.token``` because ```req.body``` is empty but i dont know why

Comment: Here are some of the reasons that `req.body` can be empty.  1) No body was sent with the request, 2) The body wasn't proper JSON, 3) The content-type wasn't `application/json`  4) Something else was eating up the request body before `express.json()` got to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved the problem. In query:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/refresh
Content-Type: "application/json"
```

should have removed the quotation marks.

Correct version:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/refresh
Content-Type: application/json
```

Thank you for your help.